# How do I create a JMSEPATH expression that outputs matched "keys" in the JSON results?

Tags: json

Using the JMEspath expression:

```
{"Resources": {"vals": Resources.*.val}}
```

against this JSON input:

```
{ "Resources": {
    "key1": {"val": 1, "foo":11},
    "key2": {"val": 1337, "foo":12},
    "key3": {"val": 3, "foo":13},
    "key4": {"foo": 42}
}}
```

produces the following expected results

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "vals": [
      1,
      1337,
      3
    ]
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I output the 'matched' keys in the output, to produce this result:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "key1": {"val": 1},
    "key2": {"val": 1337},
    "key3": {"val": 3}
  }
}
```

Comment: A related question: Are JMESPATH filter projections only available on arrays?